# jQuery how to select value from variable

Tags: jquery, variables

If I have a variable with ~15 values inside (for example images), is it possible to output the first value from that variable in a div by using a click? And if I click again select the second value from that variable? I can't seem to find anything about this.

The var

```
var images = [
  'dali.jpg',
  'illusionisme.png',
  'impresionisme.jpg',
  'popart.jpg',
  'abstracter.jpg',
]
```

The click, but this puts all the variabls inside the .art div.

```
$(".art").click(function(){
  $(".art").each(function(){
    $(this).find("img").remove();
    $(this).prepend('<img src="assets/images/' + images + '">');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. But you can try this

```
var index = 0;
    $(".art").click(function(){
        $(".art").each(function(){
            $(this).find("img").remove();
            $(this).prepend('<img src="assets/images/' + images[index] + '">');
        });
                    index++;
    });
```

What this code will do is, it will start from `0` , which is first item in your array. Then each time you click, it will put your image name in the image src attribute AND increment `index` so that next time when you click it will load the next file.

If you want the images to rotate after the last image then replace `index++;` with following code:

```
if(index < images.length-1 ){
            index++;
        }
        else{
            index = 0;
        }
```

Comment: To avoid the image become `undefined`, make sure to reset the index when the last entry is hit. @Nis also mind the zero-index, so it should check for length - 1. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mvTpv/1/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It does work, but I would like to expand a little bit on it. (Thanks for the explanation of the code btw). As you can see I have *.each* in my code, this is because I have 3 divs called .art. Each div has the same function, to put an image from the variable inside it. 

At the moment all the div's have the same image, is it possible to have each take the next image from the variable?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma for that you can move the `index++;` or most preferably its replacement code _the one that loops images_ in previous loop... Means put it immediately after `$(this).prepend.....;` statement.

Comment: I knew that it was possible, just didn't know where to put it! Great tip. The index++ does seem like something magic at the moment. Is there a jquery page that explains it?

Comment: Well... `index++` is basic JavaScript (or any programming language). Check here  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp.  As mentioned previously, instead of `index++`, its **far better** to use the other version where images are looped. Otherwise at the end of the array you will end up with `undefined` image source

Comment: @nis ...avoid suggesting people to visit and learn from w3schools. They have done and still do harm to the programming community with sloppy code explanations and resources. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ is a far better professional site cared by the community.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma why not simply change that image `src` attribute?

Comment: Why not `index=(index+1)%images.length` ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing and than appending again an `img`, **just change it's `SRC` attribute**

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/calek/2/edit)

```
var images = [/*...*/];
var n = images.length;
var i = 0;
$(".art").click(function(){
    $('img', this)[0].src = "assets/images/"+ images[++i%n] ;
});
```

Thanks to the *Reminder Operator %* you can loop infinitely your Array of images

---

If you want to **change images to every `.art` element** than you can do like:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/calek/4/edit)**

```
var images = [/*...*/];
var n = images.length;
var i = 0;                   // Index counter
var $art = $('.art');        // Cache your elements!

$art.click(function(){
  ++i;                       // Pre-increment our counter (once) on click.
  $art.each(function(idx){   // Get element's index into idx
    $('img', this)[0].src = images[(i+idx) % n] ; // Change src and loop
  });
});
```